# Refreshing id token using 'prompt=none' does not support redirect URL with custom scheme in Azure

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We are creating a Xamarin Forms app, only Android for now, which connects to a web API also created by us (ASP.Net Core). I have managed to get OpenId Connect authentication working by:

- Using Azure as the identity provider.
- Using Android custom tabs to show the Microsoft's login page.
- Detect when the custom tab is redirected to our redirect URL.
- Get the id token and use it as the authentication bearer token sent to our web API.
- Using JwtBearer authentication in the web API.

The problem appears when the id token expires. We want to get a new one without asking the user any question.

To do that, we repeat the authentication process by adding the `prompt=none`, `id_token_hint=THE_TOKEN` and `login_hint=THE_USER` parameters in the authentication request, as defined in the OpenId Connect specification, and supported by Azure.

During that request, we have an issue with the redirect URL:

1. If the redirect URL has a custom scheme (like `myapp://...`) Azure responds with an `interaction_required` error.
2. If the redirect URL has an HTTPS scheme, then Azure responds successfully (including the necessary parameters to continue the process), but I am not able to detect the redirect URL in the Android custom tab. So my app gets stuck in the custom tab trying to load my invalid redirect URL.

The explanation for #2 is that HTTPS URLs are handled by the browser (Chrome in this case), so it does not trigger any action that I can detect from my app. This seems reasonable.
I also tried to detect custom tab navigation events from Xamarin, trying to detect the event "manually", but failed. Such events are never triggered.

Now, as for #1, I do not have any reasonable explanation. So my question is:

Is there any way to make Azure accept a redirect URL with a custom scheme when trying to refresh an id token by using the standard `prompt=none` OpenId Connect parameter?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm stuck in the same situation, there doesn't seem to be a way to use custom url schemes while using `prompt=none` which makes the UX of refreshing a token a nightmare.

Comment: No, we did not. As a result, we abandoned this approach and started using a third party service for authentication. This third party provides an interface with which we could complete the work and provide a reasonable UX regarding authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems that we'll have to do the same since there's no way that this UX is accepted. I asked on the Microsoft forums but there doesn't seem to be a fix unless you use their whitelisted `msauth://` redirect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/269245/oidc-authentication-doesn39t-support-custom-url-sc.html?childToView=272226